# convert data steps from SAS to Pandas - efficient handling of SAS arrays

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, sas

I have numerous codes in SAS focused on data management of different data sets. However, my university no longer provides license, and so I have decided to convert to Python using Pandas. However, the solution that I am using seems to be inefficient, especially when handling lists of two or three dimensions.

Here is an example of the original SAS code:

```
  array educol{&ni}      educoli1 - educoli&ni; * college education with degree;
  array noqual{&ni}      noquali1 - noquali&ni; * no qualification;
  
  array eduin{&ni}       dummis bedqual cedqual dedqual eedqual fedqual gedqual hedqual check;
  
  do i=1;
     if indata{i}=1 and topqual3 notin (.) then do;
        educol{i}=(topqual3=1);
        noqual{i}=(topqual3=7);
     end;
  end;  

  do i=2 to &ni;
     if eduin{i} notin (.,0) then do;
        educol{i}=(eduin{i}=1);
        noqual{i}=(eduin{i}=7);
     end;
  end;
```

Here is how I converted it to Python:

```
####################Education####################
def indataf(indata,x,function=None):
    if indata==1:
        if function:
            x = function(x)
        return x
    else:
        return np.NaN


indata = ['indata' +str(x) for x in range(ni)]
datacore = utils.createColumns(datacore, indata, datatype="uint8")
indatain = utils.variableParse("""  aindata   bindata    cindata    dindata    eindata    findata     gindata    hindata    iindata""")

for i in range(ni):
    datacore[indata[i]]=datacore[indatain[i]].apply(lambda x: 1 if x==1 else 0)

educol = ['educol'+str(x) for x in range(ni)] #college education with degree
noqual = ['noqual'+str(x) for x in range(ni)] #no qualification

#create columns for these variable names (by default NaN) using pre-written function to generate empty columns for the specified names)
datacore = utils.createColumns(datacore, educol)
datacore = utils.createColumns(datacore, noqual)

#declare original variables as input list
eduin = utils.variableParse(""" dummis bedqual cedqual dedqual eedqual fedqual gedqual hedqual iedqual """)

datacore[educol[0]] = datacore.apply(lambda x: indataf(x[indata[0]], x['topqual3'], function=lambda x: (1 if x==1 else 0) if pd.notna(x) else np.NaN), axis=1)
datacore[noqual[0]] = datacore.apply(lambda x: indataf(x[indata[0]], x['topqual3'], function=lambda x: (1 if x==7 else 0) if pd.notna(x) else np.NaN), axis=1)
    
for i in range(1,ni):
    datacore[educol[i]] = datacore.apply(lambda x: indataf(x[indata[i]], x[eduin[i]], function=lambda x: (1 if x==1 else 0) if pd.notna(x) else np.NaN), axis=1)
    datacore[noqual[i]] = datacore.apply(lambda x: indataf(x[indata[i]], x[eduin[i]], function=lambda x: (1 if x==7 else 0) if pd.notna(x) else np.N

So, in this code as counterparts to SAS arrays I use Python lists. Effectively they are lists of lists, because each educol[i] for example is a dataframe column for the corresponding i - which is wave of data collection in my case.
```

However, this treatment seems to be not very efficient, and sometimes, when the number of dimensions in a list is more than two, results in error messages or prohibitively long processing. So, I have started searching for a way to work with lists which is more efficient. And I think that I should be looking either for list conversions or pure functions with lists. However, the difficulty that I encountered is to write a function which involves operations on elements of two or three lists. My lists are all of the same dimension and the operations are perform on an an element by element basis.

Here is an example of the function I had in mind:

```
def indatafcond(indata,xin,xinvalue,xcond=None,xcondvalue=None):
    if indata==1:
        if pd.notna(xin):
            if xcond in xcondvalue:
                x = int(xin in xinvalue)
            else:
                return np.NaN
        return x
    else:
        return np.NaN
```

This function involves three lists - indata, xin and xcond - and the operation is performed using 1st element of each lists, then 2nd element of each list, and so on, and then writes it into a list which is of the same dimension element by element.

I feel that this is a pretty standard researcher's problem, but somehow my extensive search into how best to get this done in Python using Pandas and Numpy or perhaps Dask have not been successful. I will be very thankful for any advice that I can try.

Comment: Academics on Demand and SAS UE are still free, though UE is being deprecated later this year. Neither require you to be a student and if the usage was legal under the school license (ie research, coursework) it's still fine for On Demand or UE.

Comment: Thank you. I am not 100% sure how that would work witht he data licensing that one has to agree to when using secondary data.